# If $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$, is $f(x)$ continuous on $(a,b)$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f(x)$ is a differentiable function on $(a,b)$.

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ - False - Counterexample $1/x$

Now I should prove that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$

I know that $f'$ exists by the theorem in the book.
Please help.

Comment: How is the function $x\mapsto1/x$ a counterexample, and to what exactly?

Comment: It's even better: if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: 1/x is diff. on (0,1) but not defined at f(0) so not cont. on [0,1]

Answer (score 3):

If $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists then in particular the numerator must tend to $0$.